# Email Intent not working in another activity

Tags: android, email, android-intent, flags

I am trying to open an email intent from my application. It was giving an error for the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

So I added this flag but still my app is crashing without catching any exception.

```
try {
    Intent emailIntent 
    = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
                 Uri.fromParts("mailto", email, null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Battery Dead");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ghjghjg");
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        
}
```

It works fine in a new project in mainActivity and this opens a select box for user and he selects which app he wants to use to send email but it doesn't work when i open it from another activity

Comment: "but still my app is crashing without catching any exception" -- then how do you know that it is crashing? "but it doesn't work when i open it from another activity" -- then perhaps you should provide *all* the relevant code, not just the snippet that works. In this case, we would need to see how you are getting to this snippet in "another activity".

Comment: oh found it. i was making a silly mistake. wasn't adding the activity to the manifest file. My bad.

Comment: Please consider using a proper mailto URI, i.e. one that contains the subject and the text. The Extras are only documented to work with ACTION_SEND and ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE. I wrote a bit on this topic the other day: https://medium.com/@cketti/android-sending-email-using-intents-3da63662c58f